# How to Understand Space Complexity of Happy Number Problem Solution from Leetcode

Tags: python, hashset, space-complexity

I have some difficulties in understanding the space complexity analysis for one solution for the [Happy Number Question from Leet code](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/), for my doubts on complexity analysis, I **marked them in bold** and really appreciate your advice

Here is the question:

Link: https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/

Question:

> Write an algorithm to determine if a number is "happy". A happy number
>   is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any
>   positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its
>   digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it
>   will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1.
>   Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Example:

Input: 19

Output: true

Explanation:

1^2(square of 1) + 9^2 = 82

8^2 + 2^2 = 68

6^2 + 8^2 = 100

1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1

Here is the code:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def isHappy(self, n):
        #getnext function will compute the sum of square of each digit of n
        def getnext(n):
            totalsum = 0
            while n>0:
                n,v = divmod(n,10)
                totalsum+=v**2
            return totalsum
        #we declare seen as a set to track the number we already visited
        seen = set()
        #we stop checking if: either the number reaches one or the number was visited #already(ex.a cycle)
        while n!=1 and (n not in seen):
            seen.add(n)
            n = getnext(n)
        return n==1
```

Note: feel free to let me know if I need to explain how the code works

**The solution says the space complexity is logN, could anyone give me some advice on why it is the case?**

Comment: This seems like more of a mathematics question. You can look at the average complexity for each digit to get a start. How many loops before each digit(1-9)  hits the loop at 1? Take the average of that. Then it's just a matter of multiplying the length of your input number by the average complexity you found for digits.